# procedure of proving that a number is rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I prove the following ? :

[image]

Comment: Can you show that $p^2\in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: You can't prove that. It's wrong. Imagine p^5 = 2

Answer (score 6):

HINT : $$5\times 3-7\times 2=1.$$